# Getting contant values of Environment Events from rpi-node-red-oi-sense-hat

Tags: iot, node-red

I installed node-red-node-pi-sense-hat-simulator on windows 10 and tried to generate the Environmental values but getting same values for temp pressure and humidity as 20 80 1000 respectively.

Please help in resolving the issue.

How to get random values of environment events Temp Pressure and Humidity with HAT Sensor?

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76694197/edit) the question to supply a lot more detail here, explain exactly what you've done (e.g. are you using the node's web interface to change the values?)

Answer (score 0):

The simulator node does not generate random values.

But you can change the values it outputs by clicking on the link in the docs sidebar for the sense-hat-in node. This will open a page that will allow you to change the values and to trigger joystick inputs and see the LED output.

[image: doc sidebar]

[image: Simulator output]